# How to fix this error: NotFoundHttpException in Controller.php?

Tags: laravel, seo

I receive this error message:

NotFoundHttpException in Controller.php line 269: Controller method not found.

Can anyone help me fix this error message?  Here all the codes that is related to the error message:

HomeController.php

```
public function postSeo(Request $request)
{



   $data = array('meta_title' => $request->get('meta_title'),
               'meta_keyword' => $request->get('meta_keyword'),
               'meta_description' => $request->get('meta_description')
               );


   DB::table('meta')->where('meta_id', '1')
                    ->update($data);

   return redirect('/home/article');                

}
```

routes.php

```
 Route::post('/home/article', [
     'uses' => 'HomeController@postSeo'
 ]);
```

articles.blade.php

```
 <label>SEO</label><br><br>

                                                <table width="350px">
                                                <form action="{{ action('HomeController@postSeo')}}" method="post">
                                                {{ csrf_field() }}      

                                                <tr>
                                                <td>Meta Title</td>
                                                <td><input type="text" value="" name="meta_title"></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                <td>Meta Keyword</td>
                                                <td><input type="text" value="" name="meta_keyword"></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                <td>Meta Description</td>
                                                <td><input type="text" value="" name="meta_description"></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                <td><br><br><input type="submit" value="update"></td>
                                                <td></td>
                                                </tr>

                                                </form>
                                                </table>
```

Comment: When do you get the error? On submitting the form? You're redirecting to `/home/article'`, have you set the get route for this?

Comment: On Submitting the form.  No that's the only routes for this.

Comment: You're missing the route that you're redirecting. When you redirect to `/home/article`, you need to define a `get` route for it. Just redirect to another location or add new get route to display something after you update.

Answer (score 0):

After updating you're redirecting to `/home/article`, which is a get route. Looks like you haven't defined this route. You either need to add this route or redirect somewhere else.

```
Route::post('/home/article', 'HomeController@postSeo');
Route::get('/home/article', 'HomeController@showSeo');
```

If you don't have a need for a get route for this, then find an appropriate page to redirect.

Comment: I change the route to:      Route::post('/home/article', 'HomeController@postSeo');  Why do I need both get and post route?

Comment: In your `postSeo ` method you do this `return redirect('/home/article');`, so you need to define that route, which is a get route. If you don't want to then redirect to some other location.

Comment: If I do that then what should in write in public function showSeo(request $request) {  ? }

Comment: You don't necessarily have to create this route and show something there. For example you can redirect the user back to the page where they updated. `return back();` or `return redirect()->back();`

Comment: I have a quick question:  is everything after the domain name needs to be routed to proceed?

Comment: Yes, laravel needs you to define a route to every link you use. If you try accessing a link without a route defined, you'd get an error.